# Xamarin Android custom gallery gridview

Tags: c#, android, gridview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to implement a simple custom gallery to display all photos of my phone using Xamarin.Android.
For that I use a Gridview with an adapter and create thumbnails with

> MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.GetThumbnail

But this method is slow for a big amount of photos, so I've create a Task in order to make it async. Also add CancellationToken on GetView method to cancel multiple same task in parallel.

But something goes wrong and my app crashes without messages or sometimes "**outofmemory exeception**".

**EDITED CODE**

Here my Adapter :

```
public class ImageAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    public bool IsScrolling = false;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private ICursor cursorImage;
    private ViewHolder selectedItem;
    private Bitmap blanckBitmap;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context)
    {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        mContext = context;

        String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id, MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.DateTaken };
        String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.DateTaken + " DESC";

        cursorImage = Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri,
            columns,
            null,
            null,
            orderBy);

        blanckBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.Argb4444);
    }

    public override int Count => cursorImage.Count;

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        CancellationTokenSource cts;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.gallery_item, parent, false);
            holder.Imageview = (ImageView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.gallery_item_thumbImage);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.Tag;
            if (holder != null)
            {
                var wraper = holder.WrapperCancellation.JavaCast<Wrapper<CancellationTokenSource>>();
                wraper?.Data.Cancel();
                holder.WrapperCancellation = wraper;
            }
        }
        holder?.Imageview.SetImageBitmap(blanckBitmap); // Set blanck bitmap

        if (holder != null && !IsScrolling)
        {
            holder.Imageview.Id = position;
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            GetImageThumbnailAsync(holder.Imageview, position, cts.Token);

            holder.WrapperCancellation = new Wrapper<CancellationTokenSource> { Data = cts };

            if (!holder.Imageview.HasOnClickListeners)
            {
                holder.Imageview.Click += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    if (selectedItem != null)
                    {
                        selectedItem.Imageview.CropToPadding = false;
                        selectedItem.Imageview.Background = null;
                    }

                    selectedItem = holder;
                    holder.Imageview.CropToPadding = true;
                    holder.Imageview.Background = mContext.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.image_border_selected);
                };
            }
        }
        convertView.Tag = holder;

        return convertView;
    }

    private async Task GetImageThumbnailAsync(ImageView imageView, int imgIndex, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var bmp = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                return null;

            cursorImage.MoveToPosition(imgIndex);
            var columnIndex = cursorImage.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id);
            var id = cursorImage.GetInt(columnIndex);

            return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.GetThumbnail(
                                                    Application.Context.ContentResolver,
                                                    id,
                                                    ThumbnailKind.MiniKind,
                                                    null);
        }, ct);

        if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (bmp != null)
                imageView.SetImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    }
}
```

The **GetImageThumbnailAsync** retrieves thumbnail from the GetView position.

And now the ViewHolder class :

```
public class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public ImageView Imageview;
    public int Id;
    public Wrapper<CancellationTokenSource> WrapperCancellation;
}

public class Wrapper<T> : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public T Data;
}
```

And the Scroll event listener :

```
imagegrid.ScrollStateChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.ScrollState != ScrollState.Idle)
            {
                imageAdapter.IsScrolling = true;
            }
            else
            {
                imageAdapter.IsScrolling = false;
                imageAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
```

Comment: You can try to use a scroll listener for your `GridView`, it's often to get OOM error when loading data during user scrolling the the UI. Try to load data when UI is stable and if the thumbnail is not loaded at that time, use a default one to replace it temporarily.

Comment: I tried to add OnScrollListenerStateChanged to only get thumbnails when scroll is not active (stable). Also I add default Bitmap when image isn't loaded yet. And finally a NotifyDataSetChanged() in the OnScrollListenerStateChanged to update the UI. (Added edit change in first post)

Answer (score 1):

It has limited memory for `Bitmap` in android(about 8M). So if you have too many images loaded, the OOM exception will be thrown.

Besides using the default image to replace the unloaded image temporarily as I suggested in the comment, we also need to cache Bitmaps.

For caching Bitmaps, you can check the official document of Google Android: [Use a Disk Cache](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap.html#disk-cache).

Comment: But in my new edited code I'm not loading a huge amount of images, only loading visibles images in GetView() method. So now, each time I need a image thumbnail I recreate it async. Not optimized but not heavy for memory...

Comment: @TGuerin, I tested your new code, actually your code works fine by my side, only if I keep scrolling for about 5-6 mins. Not sure what else can be helpful.